# Why won't JavaScript object display more than once?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to create a list of objects in JS and create them in classes. I need to be able to call them throughout the website by a simple variable. Many will be called more than once.

When I create the object, as an ID, I can call it in the HTML, but it only displays once and I can't duplicate it if I need to. If I create the object in a class format, it won't display at all.

Where am I going wrong?

Or is this not the best way to accomplish this?

```js
var myObj, x;
myObj = {"session1":"NAVIGATING AND NETWORKING THE CONFERENCE"};
x = myObj.session1;
document.getElementsByClassName("session1").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<div class="session1"></div>
<br>
<div class="session1"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt using ids. It is working for me. Remember that every element must have a unique id. Append to the innerhtml to prevent overwriting it

Comment: @chevybow, how is it working for you?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan By changing the classes to ids? I'm not sure where OP went wrong with their attempt using ids (which is intuitively easier than looping through the classes imo)

Comment: @chevybow, I thought you meant with the classes. I mostly focus on code provided :)

Comment: You are creating and setting the `innerHTML` property of the *array itself*, not the elements *of* the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the elements that `document.getElementsByClassName("session1");` returns, it's an array (you need a loop to set the `innerHTML` of all those elements). Like,

```js
var myObj, x;
myObj = {"session1":"NAVIGATING AND NETWORKING THE CONFERENCE"};
x = myObj.session1;
elems = document.getElementsByClassName("session1");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<div class="session1"></div>
<br />
<div class="session1"></div>
```

Comment: To be more specific, document.getElementsByClassName returns not an Array but an Array-like HTMLCollection that has indexed values like an Array, but not many of the Array methods.  If you want to operate on it like an Array, you can convert it to one with ye olde Array.prototype.slice.call trick, or spread operator if you're using ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as the following:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("session1")
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].innerHTML = x
}
```